# How do I use CkEditor layout on textfield input?

Tags: 8, wysiwyg

I have a content type with a "Text (formated)" field. When I try to write something in it, all my HTML is ok. But I want to use the buttons of ckEditor to make it more "user friendly". I don't want to always have to write all my tags manually.

On "Text, long (formated)" field, there is no problem.

You can see what I mean in this screenshot.

[image: My problem illustrated]

I already tried to switch text format under my field. Nothing changed, except I got more tags allowed.

Comment: Are you sure that is a text formatted _long_ and not just text formatted?

Comment: That's not a long text and that's the problem. I don't want to use a long text field for just a 2 word's phrase. But I will use it if it's not possible to use ckeditor on in formatted textfield :) Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

CKEditor only works on a textarea, you can’t attach an instance to a textfield.

You could implement `hook_form_alter` and change it from a textfield, but it’s hard to see what the point would be.

If you need long text, just use a long text field. It was designed for your use case, so will always work as expected.

Comment: I mark your reponse as the answer. Thanks for the information. I don't want to use a long text for just 2 words (it's a page title, like : "About this work" where work is bold for exemple.) But it looks that's not possible to do what I want simply. I will use a long text field so. Thanks :)

Comment: The "Text (formated)" field might be removed in the future:
https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2737499